# Spring MVC Form submission binding against dynamic nested properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am out of ideas and turning to the community experts. I am using Hibernate Single table inheritance which is driving me in this direction.

I have a BaseEntity class with many Subclasses using a Discriminator. I am using Spring MVC annotated controllers for the CRUD operations and JSPs using Spring form tags for the view.

I have a backingForm which includes the subclassed entities that the form uses. To save a ton of duplicate code I have a common.jsp that contains the fields in the BaseEntity and then other JSPs specfic to each subclasses.These other JSPs include the common.jsp. I am able to display the data fine by looknig at a pathVariable and then loading the proper subclass, adding  it to the form. Form submission and Spring's DataBinding has got me reeling.  Can any suggest a good way to allow for Spring to dymanically post to a specific nested property. Think about it like using polymorphism on a form submission. I know the may seem confusing, but idf anyone has ever tried this it should make perfect sense :-). This is not about dynamic list binding (AutoPopulating) this is very different.

Thanks for any insight at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your annotated controller you can do as a separate method:

```
@ModelAttribute("backingObject")
public SuperClass getBackingObject(HttpRequest request //etc) {
  //determine value of your path variable
  //create appropriate subcass
  return subClassInstanceForBinding;
}
```

So then when spring goes to bind it will find "backingObject" in the model map that you put there and use it, rather than looking for a constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into doing this.  Also, I think I may have found another way by using a variable in spring's form tag.  I can use the forms's tag "path" with a variable like this: <form:input path="${someVariable}.field" />. THis allows dymanic binding. I am seeing some early success so far.